# Rotating and cropping a ROI from minAreaRect() OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a program that rotates and crops an image ROI (without losing a single pixel of the frame) based just on what `minAreaRect()` returns (from seeing what it can mark with `drawContours`).

Now since I don't understand what the function returns other than the rotation angle(list [0:1]) I'm struggling to make that myself. All I found on the internet was a Stack Overflow question with code that wasn't really explained very well and didn't realy work (atleast for openCV 3.6 not)

May I have any clues to what is the return syntax of this function and what is the method and keywords to search for such things, as well as a short little function that can maybe do that rotation and cropping?  Since that looks like a quite common and simple thing to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by "openCV 3.6" -- no such version exists, the [latest released](https://opencv.org/releases.html) is 3.4.3 at the time I'm writing this comment. Version 3.6 sounds more like Python version. Could you, please, [edit] your question and clarify that?

Comment: If you read through [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) -- specifically section "7.b. Rotated Rectangle" -- you will notice that in Python `mainAreaRect` returns "( center (x,y), (width, height), angle of rotation )" -- i.e. a tuple with 3 values, the first being a pair representing the center of the rectangle (around which it is rotated), then a pair representing its size, and finally the rotation angle around the center.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly what you wish to do, you have a rotated rectangle, and you want to rotate this so that the edges are horizontal/vertical, and crop it to the size that matches the original rotated rectangle? If so, [`getRotationMatrix2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326) along with [`warpAffine`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983) are what you're looking for. After rotation, the center stays same, and you know the size, so the crop is trivial.

Comment: Did you managed to get an answer?